Creating a new line shortcut for stored procedures in query console in IntelliJ
The language I am using is plpgsql (Postgres plsql language). I have attached the image of block structure that I am trying to write.
Difficulty I am facing:

Unable to make new lines between $$ symbols via shortcut. I have attached the issue replication. The caret should place between $$ symbols to write statements. I tried complete code statement but it put caret outside $$ block.

Is there any way we can create functions that are language specifics. I knew if we press Alt+Enter in query console we can create function. But these are generic not to language specific. Every time I need to insert language explicitly.

If you can refer to video or resources where query console is used to write stored procedures or functions. I want to learn efficient way of writing them.


How can I find the solution for these problems?
Link for issue - https://youtu.be/06FaHFHetWs

